# c# - Consume soap web service with Xamarin.droid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm using xamarin studio to build my first android app, to consume a web service  and i can't find  any help in the documentation :
Click [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/)!.

I tried to watch some videos, all i found is about xamarin.forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import the web reference as a .NET 2.0 Web Services if your service is not a WCF service:

[image: Step 1]

[image: step 2]

Calling the service:

```
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            SoapApp.www.webservicex.net.GlobalWeather soapservice = new SoapApp.www.webservicex.net.GlobalWeather();
            var cities = soapservice.GetCitiesByCountry("peru");
            button.Text = cities;
        };
```

this is the result:

[image: Result]

If it doesn't work try to do that building the proxy in Visual Studio in a new project and them copying the class to the Xamarin Studio project, i know it isn't the best way to do it but is a workaround.

Dont forget to add the `System.Web.Services` and `System.ServiceModel` references.

Sorry for the spanish verions of Xamarin Studio, hope it helps you